# adding a link to image within ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to modify an existing project.

The page shows a list of thumbnails and links to projects.

```
link_to project_listing.company image_tag project_listing.thumbnail.url(:normal
link_to project_listing.company, project_path(project_listing)
```

What I would like to do is make the thumbnail also link to the project page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag('image.png', :alt => "back"), project_path(project_listing) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your code snippet above. If you want the thumbnail to be a link to project path use the following:

```
<%= link_to project_path(project_listing) do %>
    <%= image_tag project_listing.thumbnail.url(:normal) %>
<% end %>
```